# How to pass value from one intent to another in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

My app is giving user types of news based on the input. For ex: If user is saying what is happening in sports, so I give user sports news in the form of `compound card`. Now if user is saying that "Show me similar news", so all i need to do is pass the category id of that news to my other file and process that category id to get more same type of news. I am unable to pass the category id.

My news details file is NewsSearch.model.bxb and input i have taken is categoryName, which I convert into id and pass it to my api.

My similar News file is SimilarNews.model.bxb and input is categoryId, which I am supposed to pass to my api to get the same category news.

How to pass categoryId from NewsSearch.model.bxb to SimilarNews.model.bxb?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to a Continuation. If NewsSearch concept is not marked as transient, you can create an Action `SearchSimilarNews` that will take NewsSearch as the input. Since this is a followup query, NewsSearch will be available to the Planner from a historical perspective and will therefore be automatically passed into the input.

You may want to look at the Continuation sample capsule for more ideas https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/tree/master/continuation-for-training